# comparison sort algorithms requires Ω(nlgn) comparisons in the worst case

Tags: algorithm, sorting

This was taken from the popular book called Intro to Algorithms. The author states that any comparison sort algorithm requires Ω(nlgn) comparisons in the worst case. Taking the bubble sort algorithm as an example, in the worst case we have an upper bound O(n^2). Omega represents the lower or least bound therefore wouldn't the lower bound of a worst case be Ω(n^2) as well? How would a bubble sort have a lower bound, such as the suggested Ω(nlgn), rather than n^2 in a worst case performance? In the worst case performance bubble sort can't take AT LEAST nlgn.

Comment: Since `n^2` dominates `n lg(n)`, bubble sort is `Ω(n lg(n))` (and `Ω(n^2)`).

Comment: There are algorithms (not bubble sort) that have a worst case of `O(n lg n)`.  Every algorithm must have `Ω(nlgn)`; some algorithms get closer to that bound than others.

Comment: To amplify Tavian Barnes, every function in Ω(n^2) also is in Ω(n log n).

Comment: I still do not understand...Since omega defines the lower bound, depending on what our case performance is for bubble sort, we may have a different lower bound. In a best case scenario bubble sort should take Ω(n) but in a worst case scenario we will have to go through the array n times therefore our upper bound should be 0(n^2) and our lower bound for the worst case scenario should also be Ω(n^2). In a worst case scenario you cannot sort any faster than n^2 and since omega represents the least bound how can we say "oh yes in the worst case scenario you can run as fast as nlgn"?

Comment: I meant to say we will have to go through the array n^2 times therefore our upper bound

Comment: Time to haul out the quantifiers. The precise meaning of the lower bound is that, for every correct, deterministic, comparison-based sorting algorithm, for every integer n >= 0, there exists an input array of length n such that the algorithm uses at least lg (n!) comparisons.

Comment: you say uses at least, meaning it can be greater than lg(n!). Here it is talking about the worst case scenario, shouldn't that lower bound be more than lg(n!)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To oversimplify slightly*, when we talk about lower bounds for algorithmic problems, we're interested in how the *best* algorithm does in the *worst* case. The best comparison-based sorting algorithms (e.g., mergesort) use roughly n log n comparisons in the worst case, so the lower bound for sorting is quoted as Omega(n log n). Algorithms that are not the best, e.g., bubble sort, may do materially worse than the best algorithm in the worst case. In the best case, they may do better than the best algorithm. Neither of these facts is inconsistent with the lower bound for sorting.

*There may not be one *best* algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

The author said ANY algorithm: no algorithm can do better than `Ω(N Log(N))` in the worst case.

The reason is easy to understand: any comparison-based sorting algorithm is a binary decision tree (a long, dynamic sequence of if-then-else). Since the algorithm must be able to process any permutation of the data, it must be able to permute differently all `N!` cases and the tree must have at least that many leaves. So the height of the decision tree, i.e. the worst-case complexity, is at least `Lg(N!)=Ω(N.Log(N))`.

When the decision tree is well balanced (Heapsort), the height is also `O(N.Log(N))`.

When the decision tree is strongly imbalanced (Bubblesort), the height can become `O(N²)`.

---

**Addendum**:

As `Ω` denotes a lower bound, any lower lower bound is also valid. So as the worst case of Bubble sort is `Θ(N²)`, it is also `Ω(N²)`, `Ω(N.Log(N))`, `Ω(N)`, `Ω(Log N)`, `Ω(1)`...

Answer (score 0):

You need to focus on what "at least" means, denoted by `Ω`.

"Bubble sort requires `Ω(nlg(n))` comparisons in the worst case" is not a False statement, because it DOES require AT LEAST `knlg(n)` comparisons for some constant `k`.

Yes, we know that bubble sort requires `Ω(n^2)` in the worst case. However, this does not make the above statement False. Thus what the author claims is correct.

Here's an exmaple, hopefully to clarify the situation:

"I can do at least 50 push-ups regardless of how tired I am"

So knowing that, is the following statement False?

"I can do at least 20 push-ups regardless of how tired I am"

Answer (score 0):

> The author states that any comparison sort algorithm requires Ω(nlgn) comparisons in the worst case.

There are several ways to think about the wording of this claim, with increasing degrees of formalism/pedantry.

Most colloquially: Read the phrase "*any* comparison sort algorithm" as "the best comparison-based sorting algorithm you can think of." Bubblesort doesn't even enter the picture, because mergesort is better (in the worst case). It's analogous to something like "*Any* airplane will stall when its airspeed drops below 1mph." Some airplanes will stall sooner, but *even the best airplane you can think of* won't be able to beat the claim.

Slightly more formally: Insert the words "at least." Any comparison-based sorting algorithm requires *at least* Ω(nlgn) comparisons in the worst case. Some require even more than that.

Slightly more formally: Observe that the Ω-notation is already defined to mean "at least," so, really, you don't have to say it. Saying "at least Ω(nlgn)" is redundant, like saying "ATM machine" or "PIN number." Likewise, the big O-notation is defined to mean "at most." Bubblesort *is* O(n²). "But when you give it sorted input, it runs in linear time!" Yes; when we say "O(n²)" we mean it takes *at most* quadratic time. It's allowed to take less in some cases. Similarly, a naïvely implemented quicksort is Ω(nlgn). "But when you give it adversarial input, it runs in quadratic time!" Yes; when we say "Ω(nlgn)" we mean it takes *at least* time proportional to nlgn. It's allowed to take more in some cases.

Formally (AFAIK): In fact, the O and Ω notations refer to *sets of functions*.

- The set O(1) is defined as the set of all functions *f* such that ∃*c*∀*n*: *f*(*n*) < *c*. (Sorry, [StackOverflow doesn't support math markup.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/latex-on-stack-overflow))
- The set O(*n*²) is the set of all functions *f* such that ∃*c*∀*n*: *f*(*n*) < *cn*². Notice that O(1) ⊂ O(*n*) ⊂ O(*n*²).
- Ω is the same idea with the sign flipped: The set Ω(*n* lg *n*) is the set of all functions *f* such that ∃*c*∀*n*: *f*(*n*) > *cn* lg *n*. Notice that Ω(1) ⊃ Ω(*n*) ⊃ Ω(*n*²).

So, your book is basically saying that if we consider the function *g<sub>A</sub>(n) = number of comparisons made by algorithm A on an input of size n*, where *A* represents a comparison-based sorting algorithm, then

- ∀A: *g*<sub>A</sub> ∈ Ω(*n* lg *n*)

which is to say

- ∀A: ∃*c*∀*n*: *g*<sub>A</sub>(*n*) > *cn* lg *n*

(That is, it is *impossible* to find any comparison-based sorting algorithm A such that ∀*c*∃*n*: *g*<sub>A</sub>(*n*) < *cn* lg *n*.)

Answer (score -2):

1. ```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.8/d3.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
   ```

Comment: Code-only answer are of little interest.

Comment: What does this answer have to do with the question asked?